# Form web part not displaying all data on public facing site with AAM configured

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alternate-access-mapping

I have an intranet with Alternate Access mapping configured with an internet site(www.).

Now what ever changes I make in my Intranet site I get the changes reflected on the internet facing site.

I have added one form web part which contains a submit button along with general text fields and two check box fields where I have a link to download a particular document.

When I deploy this web part in my intranet site I get the contents as required. But when I move to internet site, the checkboxes along with the download links are missing from the webpart, although other text fields along with submit button is appearing.

I checked the permission of the links, and I am able to access it separately.

Using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved.. There were one more web.config file having RootURL property for the user control. Assigned the root url as the internet url and it fixed the issue.